# Can't add rows of data to QTablewidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

I'm developing a small app that updates some tables dynamically using user input through clicking entries on list widgets, the last step of the selection process involves a Qtablewidget displaying the info the user has selected ordered neatly on columns and rows, my problem is that I can't seem to add data to my qtablewidget, in the code below you can see the function that is getting called to add an item to the table, currently its just a string saying 'test' being printed in the 6 columns in the 1st row but when it is executed it doesn't add anything to the table, I even placed an "I'm working" message to make sure it runs and it does run, it just doesn't add the data to the table.

```
   def plantaget(item):
     A = item.text()
     row = str(regionmanager)
     print(row)
     for i in range(1,6,1):
      print('Im Working')
      self.tableWidget_2.setItem(i,1,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('test'))
```

Here is the code of the tablewidget:

```
    self.tableWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.tab_3)
    self.tableWidget_2.setObjectName("tableWidget_2")
    self.tableWidget_2.setColumnCount(7)
    self.tableWidget_2.setRowCount(0)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(5, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.tableWidget_2.setHorizontalHeaderItem(6, item)
```

To save some time I used QTDesigner to make the gui so the code for the table is more extensive than normal it seems, since it has a ui translation class right after that has this code:

```
    item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "RM"))
    item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Plant"))
    item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Salaried"))
    item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Technical"))
    item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Indirect Operator"))
    item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(5)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Direct Operator"))
    item = self.tableWidget_2.horizontalHeaderItem(6)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Date"))
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: You're not "adding" rows, you're trying to set an item for a row, and that row might not even exist unless you properly called [`setRowCount()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#setRowCount) or [`insertRow()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#insertRow).

Comment: @musicamante It makes much more sense now, thanks.